# How to embed a received text from database to textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am using

> nicEdit-latest.js

editor in my website to add some text to database , my problem is when i want to edit that text , it deosn't appear.

```
<textarea name="body" value=" <?php echo $my_text ;?> " ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text of a textarea is put inside the tags `textarea`, not inside the attribute "value".

**Like this:**

```
<textarea name="body"><?php echo $my_text; ?></textarea>
```

But i think maybe the problem isn't there. Check if the variable my_text was declared and debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place text in between the textarea tags. Not like value="$var", but like this:

```
<textarea name="body"><?php echo $my_text ;?> </textarea>
```